# Remove duplicate elements from array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of `reactions` where every user is allowed to have only one reaction per message:

```json
const reactions = [
  {
    id: "c9c5a273-6033-4239-a6f4-09c067633680",
    profile: {
      first_name: "Pete",
      id: "1",
    },
    reaction_type: "love",
  },
  {
    id: "2e94ee98-7d84-49c5-ac69-600a76d90012",
    profile: {
      first_name: "Eve",
      id: "3",
    },
    reaction_type: "love",
  },
  {
    id: "2e94ee98-7d84-49c5-ac69-600a76d90013",
    profile: {
      first_name: "Brad",
      id: "4",
    },
    reaction_type: "thumbs_up",
  },
  {
    id: "30511fa3-3574-44f4-93f0-04ee35edc62b",
    profile: {
      first_name: "John",
      id: "2",
    },
    reaction_type: "lol",
  },
  {
    id: "30511fa3-3574-44f4-93f0-04ee35edc62b",
    profile: {
      first_name: "Bill",
      id: "5",
    },
    reaction_type: "thumbs_up",
  },
];
```

Since there could be duplicate `reaction_type`, I want to keep only "my" reaction, eg. I'm user with `id:4` and then remove duplicates of all the other reactions. I don't care witch user will be removed from the array.

Right now I'm using this logic:

```js
const uid = "4";

const uniqueReactions = () => {
  const myReactions = [];
  reactions.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.profile.id === uid) {
      myReactions.push(item);
    }
  });

  if (myReactions.length) {
    const uniques = reactions
      .filter((reaction) => {
        return (
          reaction.reaction_type !== myReactions[0].reaction_type &&
          reaction.profile.id !== uid
        );
      })
      .reduce(
        (r, i) =>
          !r.some(
            (j) => i.reaction_type === j.reaction_type && i.profile.id !== uid
          )
            ? [...r, i]
            : r,
        []
      );
    return [...myReactions, ...uniques];
  } else {
    return reactions.reduce(
      (r, i) =>
        !r.some((j) => i.reaction_type === j.reaction_type) ? [...r, i] : r,
      []
    );
  }
};
```

Is there a better way on handling this? It feels messy and noisy.

**Edit**: just for clarity, I want to keep "my" reaction so I can highlight it with a different color in the UI.

Comment: What happens in case user `'4'` (the OP) appears more than just once within the `reaction` items with another `reaction_type` than just `'thumbs_up'`? Should all other reaction items be ignored likewise?

Comment: @PeterSeliger users are allowed to only have one reaction per message

Comment: Got it, and a message then gets identified by an `reaction` item's `id` value?

Comment: Above the message i represent the `reaction_type`, so if a message has 10 `love` and 5 `thumb_up` it will only show 1 heart and 1 thumb up icon. Hope this covers what you asked.

Edit: my reaction will be highlighted in a different color than the others.

Comment: I'm asking how one identifies a message, since the OP says ... _**"users are allowed to only have one reaction per message"**_ ... and the data shows e.g. twice the user `'John'`/`id: '2'` with different `reaction_type`s under the same reaction's `id`, whereas other `id` values are distinct. The best might be to come up with a good enough set of input data and in addition provide the expected result.

Comment: You're right, the duplicate reaction slipped in from my tests, will edit the question. Every reaction has a `message_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what mostly makes it messy is the abundant use of ternary and one letter variable names.

That said, I think it could be simpler. Here's my attempt at it:

```
function getUniqueReactions(id, reactions) {
    const userTypes = reactions
        .filter(reaction => reaction.profile.id === id)
        .map(reaction => reaction.reaction_type);
    const processedTypes = [];
    
    return reactions.reduce((accumulator, curItem) => {
        const { reaction_type: curType } = curItem; // The current type
        
        // If the current user has posted this type but this isn't the current user, skip the item
        if (userTypes.includes(curType) && curItem.profile.id !== id) {
            return accumulator;
        }
        
        // Check if either we're the supplied user and the type matches
        // or this is a reaction type the user hasn't posted and we haven't seen yet
        if (curItem.profile.id === id || !processedTypes.includes(curType)) {
            accumulator.push(curItem);
            processedTypes.push(curType);
        }
        
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
}

console.log(getUniqueReactions("4", reactions));
```